# G-mean custom metric Tidymodels R

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am trying to create a custom metric for evaluation using tidymodels in R. I want to compute the G-mean, which is the sqrt(sensitivity * specificity). I have tried to create the following function, but it is not working. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
event_col <- function(xtab, event_level) {
  if (identical(event_level, "first")) {
    colnames(xtab)[[1]]
  } else {
    colnames(xtab)[[2]]
  }
}

g_mean_vec <- function(truth, 
                          estimate, 
                          estimator = NULL, 
                          na_rm = TRUE, 
                          event_level = "first",
                          ...) {
  estimator <- finalize_estimator(truth, estimator)
  
  g_mean_rate_impl <- function(truth, estimate) {
    # Create 
    sqrt(sensitivity * specificity)
  }
  
  metric_vec_template(
    metric_impl = g_mean_impl,
    truth = truth,
    estimate = estimate,
    na_rm = na_rm,
    cls = "factor",
    estimator = estimator,
    ...
  )
}

g_mean <- function(data, ...) {
  UseMethod("g_mean")
}
g_mean <- new_class_metric(g_mean, direction = "maximize")

g_mean.data.frame <- function(data, truth, estimate, na_rm = TRUE, ...) {
  metric_summarizer(
    metric_nm = "g_mean",
    metric_fn = g_mean_vec,
    data = data,
    truth = !!enquo(truth),
    estimate = !!enquo(estimate),
    na_rm = na_rm,
    ...
  )
}
```

Comment: In general, be specific *"it is not working"*. I'm going to guess, though: your function takes arguments `truth, estimate` but you calculate `sensitivity * specificity`, which are never passed or defined.

Comment: Also you're defining `g_mean` twice.

Answer (score 0):

I would emulate [the code in the package](https://github.com/tidymodels/yardstick/blob/main/R/class-j_index.R) for the J Index (sensitivity + specificity - 1). That is similar enough to what you are doing to be pretty straightforward.

There are a few issues with the code above. Maybe take a look at the [developer page for creating new metrics](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/metrics/)